Understanding why $\frac{\phi^5}{2}$ solves this 3D optimization problem, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio
I would like to understand the deep meaning of a solution which arises from an optimization problem discussed in a paper of mine since it can be simply stated as $\frac{\phi^5}{2}$, where $\phi := \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the well-known golden ratio.
The problem asks to join all the vertices of the cube $[0,1]^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ (i.e., working in the Euclidean space) by using a polygonal chain consisting of the minimum number of line segments. Then, under the stated constraint, we are going to minimize the volume of the axis-aligned bounding box (AABB) which contains the above-mentioned polygonal chain with minimum link-length.
In order to solve the problem, we have proven that, for each integer $k > 1$, the minimum-link polygonal chains joining all the points of the set $\{0,1\}^k$ have (exactly) $3 \cdot 2^{k-2}$ edges (see Theorems 2.2 and 2.3), and thus our optimal polygonal chains consist of $6$ line segments.
I initially thought that the original question was sufficiently articulated to prevent the existence of a very compact solution.
Surprisingly, in recent years, I was finally able to determine that the polygonal chain $(0,1,0)-(0,0,0)-\left(\frac{1+\phi}{2},0,\frac{1+\phi}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2},1+\phi,\frac{1}{2} \right)-\left(\frac{1-\phi}{2},0,\frac{1+\phi}{2} \right)-(1,0,0)-(1,1,0)$ minimizes the volume of the AABB for the given problem (for a partial solution, see General uncrossing covering paths inside the Axis-Aligned Bounding Box, pp. 164-165).
Consequently, an optimal AABB is $\left[\frac{1-\phi}{2}, \frac{\phi+1}{2} \right]\times \left[0, 1+\phi \right]\times \left[0, \frac{1+\phi}{2} \right]$, which implies a volume of $\left(\frac{1+\phi}{2}-\frac{1-\phi}{2} \right) \cdot (1+\phi) \cdot \left(\frac{1+\phi}{2} \right)$.
Hence, the minimum volume of the AABB is $\frac{\phi \cdot (1+\phi)^2}{2}$, which can be compactly rewritten as $\frac{\phi^5}{2}$ (i.e., $\frac{11+5 \cdot \sqrt{5}}{4} \approx 5.54508497$).
My conclusion is that this outcome depends on the definition of $\phi$ as the positive root of the quadratic equation $1-x = \frac{1}{x}$ so that we can rearrange a product of three factors where $\phi$ appears trice (inside all the terms describing the lengths of the sides of the AABB) as we go up/down in the hyperoperators ladder by using the mentioned property $1-\phi = \frac{1}{\phi}$. Here, accidentally, we get a simplification by going upstairs on the mentioned ladder.
If so (and this is just an attempt to think about the effects of a property of $\phi$ rather than a deep reasoning on its meaning) the remaining subquestion would ask us to explain why $\phi$ appears as the key value for the optimal polygonal chain of $6$ links that joins all the vertices of a unit cube (and I can anticipate that we get a similar outcome also by considering circuits instead of trails).
Very curious.

P.S. I've seen that the constant $\phi^5$ is also the "critical activity" of the Hard Hexagon Model (see the OEIS sequence A244593).

You could consider posting an answer to the MO question, Golden ratio in contemporary mathematics.

Thank you very much, done!

The formula $1-\phi=\frac{1}{\phi}$ is the $n=0$ case of the generalized golden ratio relations $\phi_n-\phi_{n+1}=\frac{1}{\phi_{n+1}}$ where $\phi_{-1}=0, \phi_{n+1}=F_+(\phi_n)$ and the golden ratio map $F_+(x)=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}=x+\cfrac{1}{x+\cfrac{1}{x+\ldots}}$, see https://mathoverflow.net/q/474134. Maybe you can generalized your problem.

Thank you @CHUAKS. Maybe it would be interesting to study the same problem in higher dimensions too (e.g., for the planar case, the solution is a trivial spanning path and thus the volume of the AABB is $1 = \phi_{-1} + 1$).
